# Improving pure HTML+CSS iframe menu

Tags: html, css, iframe, menubar

I'm making a website with a very simple menu bar at the top of each page. I would like to make the menu easy to update, so hard-coding the whole menu into each page is not ideal. Modifying and re-uploading every page would be too cumbersome and since the website will be hosted statically, I cannot use PHP create the menu either.

My current solution uses an iframe and a separate html file with my menu.
This is pasted in the body of each new page:

```
<iframe src="menu.html" width="100%" height="55x" id="menuframe" style="border:none"></iframe>
```

I get this, which works nicely:

```css
<!-- This is my `theme.css` -->
#menudiv {
 width: 100%;
 height: 38px;
}
.menu-item {
 height: 20px;
 width: 120px;
 margin: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 4px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    background: 000000;
    border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<!-- This is `menu.html`: -->
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme.css">
</head>

<body>
 <div align="center"><div id="menudiv" align="center">
  <a href="index.html" title="Home" class="menu-item" target="_top">  Home  </a>
  <a href="index.html" title="Home" class="menu-item" target="_top">  About </a>
 </div></div>
</body>

</html>
```

This works fairly well for a simple menu with only a few buttons, but it doesn't scale up well. If there are enough buttons, then the iframe overflows and half the buttons will be cut in half. If I eventually move on towards a drop down menu with CSS, the menu items will be eaten by overflow and cut off, etc.

How can I make an easily editable menu for my static website?

- The menu must be editable from one file, a la `menu.html` or similar.
- I cannot use PHP.
- I have never used JavaScript/jQuery but I am open to solutions that use them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Dont use an Iframe, If you really dont want to get a hosting plan.**

Here is how you can still use a single menu template for each page.

1 You can use JQuery's load function.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#somecontainer').load('path-to-your-html');
});
```

2 Create a JavaScript file with your menu on each page.

```
   <script src="path-to-your-js"></script>
```

3 Or you can create an html page an include it on each page with:

```
 <!--#include virtual="path-to-your-html" -->
```

Comment: Static = no-php, post processing, server-side anything, etc. Just plain HTML/CSS/Client side scripting. This is offered by, eg: most cheap/free webhosts.

Comment: I understand, but at $7 a month, I see no real reason to limit yourself to static pages.